# Display properties of object in blender

Tags: 3d-view

im retopologizing for the first time in blender and was wondering how i can show doublesided display ? for the object im doing retopo for. My example in the attachement, you can see the gum and teeth and gum dissapear when i go from the bottom view.

Thanks in advance and Greetings !

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are asking "how I can show doublesided display" but if i'm understanding your problem correctly what you need is to **not** show double sided faces.

To do that open the **Viewport Shading** menu and put a check against **Backface Culling**.

[image]

Edited to add:

You appear to have a set up something like in the screen shot below:
[image]

View from below and the teath in my "snake head" are hidden (no Backface Culling):
[image]

With Backface Culling enabled teath are visible :
[image]

and finally Vieport Display > In Front unchecked:
[image]

another edit :
Perhaps for the inside where the **In Front** option is causing problems, disactivate that and use a **Offset** distance in the **Shrinkrwap modifier** to keep the faces above the high poly model as in the image below.

[image]

......... or simply assign the outside faces to a vertex group for ease of selecting/deselecting and hide them while working on the iside if the snakes head.

Comment: thanks for your reply, however i ment that the underlying geometry (teeth and gum in grey) dissapears as soon as i look from the bottom. I need to keep that party visible.

Comment: I haven't done any retopologising in Blender 2.8 so had to check, See edit in my answer for result.

Comment: In Blender 2.7 there was a option to keep the retopology faces physically above the high poly mesh. To late in the day now but I need to do a search sometime to find out how to do that in 2.8.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, i have overlooked something and that was that my mesh was fragmented different parts when importing (new to blender). All of the information you gave me was still useful.